# Extract data from Hierarchical DBSCAN in R

Tags: r, clustering

I came across this the Hierarchical DBSCAN implementation in R. Is there a way to extract the cluster values? I would like to retain the most dense cluster and eliminate the rest from the dataset, and keep the corresponding x values
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbscan/vignettes/hdbscan.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the cluster identity and filter the original data according to that:

```
library("dbscan")
data("moons")
cl <- hdbscan(moons, minPts = 5)

table(cl)
 3  1  2 
50 25 25 

most_dense = names(sort(table(cl$cluster),decreasing=TRUE)[1])

most_dense
[1] "3"

newdata= moons[cl$cluster %in% most_dense,]
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(moons,col=factor(cl$cluster),main="full data",ylim=c(-1,3))
plot(newdata,main="most dense",ylim=c(-1,3))
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! is there a way to get the corresponding x values for each cluster?

Comment: Figured it out..  which(cl$cluster %in% most_dense) gives row numbers, and from there original data can be subsetted